# Can't import the simple_salesforce package in lambda aws

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, salesforce, simple-salesforce

While trying to import simple-salesforce packages in lambda I'm getting this error
[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/USnR9.png)

```
{
  "errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'lambda_function': No module named 'simple_salesforce'",
  "errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError"
}
```

I tried zipping the packages in a Unix environment and upload it to s3 buckets before making a layer in lambda. But it's saying it can't import the module.
Below are the steps used

virtualenv v-env

python3 -m venv v-env

pip install simple-salesforce

deactivate

cd v-env/lib/python3.7/site-packages

zip -r9 ${OLDPWD}/function_sf.zip .

aws s3 cp function_sf.zip s3://my_bucket/layer_library/

Need help with importing simple-salesforce in lambda.

Comment: please elaborate on your problem

Comment: I have added some more info.  @soheshdoshi

Comment: can you try without layers to see if it works?

Comment: Lambda is throwing the same error when tried that way also. @HoratiuJeflea

Answer (score 0):

Per simple-salesforce primary documentation:

> basic Salesforce.com REST API client built for Python **2.6, 2.7, 3.3,
>   3.4, 3.5, and 3.6**

Maybe try to downgrade your env to 3.6 and try from there.

Source:
https://github.com/simple-salesforce/simple-salesforce